# BootStrap Fixed Header With Toggle Button

Tags: html, header, toggle

since yesterday, I was trying to design one specific fixed header at top position for my website.

I'm beginner for bootstrap but I know how to design fixed header on top of the screen using bootstrap. But I want to know design header using toggle option which should be simlar to the following website header:

https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/horizontal-subnavigation-in-bootstrap-3/225086

In above mentioned site, they have used toggle option at top right corner and when we click on it then it will show the items in vertical list however I want it in one horizontal list. My Design should

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I was able to complete the design part. Following code works for me:

```
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" id="topmenu">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <img src="~/Content/img/logo.png" style="padding-top:6px" class="pull-left" />

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#one">Menu1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Menu2", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Menu3", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Menu4", "Index", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel navbar-inverse" id="submenu">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav collapse" id="one">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Submenu1", "Submenu1", "Submenu1Controller")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Submenu2", "Submenu2", "Submenu2Controller")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Submenu3", "Submenu3", "Submenu3Controller")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Submenu4", "Submenu4", "Submenu4Controller")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Submenu5", "Index", "Home")</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </nav>


    <div class="container-fluid body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My Website</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>

slight adjustments to the .panel css in bootstrap.css file to make

.panel {
  margin-bottom: 0px; 
  background-color: #fff;
  border: .5px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
          box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}
```

I've changed the margin-bottom to 0px from 20px and border to .5px from 1px